# How to take inputs for strings one by one in C

Tags: c, regex, fgets

I have to take inputs like below, and print the same (only the sentences):

```
2

I can't believe this is a sentence.

aarghhh... i don't see this getting printed.
```

Digit 2 shows the number of lines to be followed (2 lines after this here).
I used all the options scanf and fgets with various regex used.

```
int main() {
  int t;
  char str[200];
  scanf ("%d", &t);      
  while (t > 0){
  /* 
  Tried below three, but not getting appropriate outputs
  The output from the printf(), should have been:

  I can't believe this is a sentence.
  aarghhh... i don't see this getting printed.
  */
    scanf ("%[^\n]", str);
    //scanf("%200[0-9a-zA-Z ]s", str);
    //fgets(str, 200, stdin);
    printf ("%s\n", str);
    t--;
  }
}
```

I am sorry, i have searched all related posts, but I am not able to find any answer to this:
All versions of scanf() produce no results, and fgets() prints only the first sentence.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A very minor note: the formating string argument used with `scanf()` and friends is *not* a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use `fgets()`. Remember that it will keep the linefeed, so you might want to remove that manually after reading the line:

```
if(scanf("%d", &t) == 1)
{
  while(t > 0)
  {
    if(fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) != NULL)
    {
      const size_t len = strlen(str);
      str[len - 1] = '\0';
      printf("You said '%s'\n", str);
      --t;
    }
    else
      printf("Read failed, weird.\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unwind!! I learned to use it in my college days, but couldn't recall. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier let's say the input is "2\none\ntwo\n".

When you start your program, before the first `scanf()` the input buffer has all of it and points to the beginning

```
2\none\ntwo
^
```

After the first `scanf()`, the "2" is consumed leaving the input buffer as

```
2\none\ntwo
 ^^
```

And now you attempt to read everything but a newline ... but the first thing in the buffer is a newline, so nothing gets read.

Suggestion: **always use `fgets()` to read full lines**, and then parse the input as you think is better.

Answer (score 0):

To use regex in C you must include `regex.h`.  In this case, you do not need regex. Where you have `"%[^\n]"`, replace it with `"%s"`.  Make sure that you include `stdio.h`.